# Using new useOPFS=true in Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Viewer version 7.96.0 states that

> New and improved geometry cache that can be enabled using the URL parameter useOPFS=true

can this option be passed also as part of the initilisation options for the viewer or only as URL parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify it as a global variable (`USE_OPFS=true`) before initializing the viewer to get the same effect as the query parameter.

Comment: What does this new parameter do exactly?

Comment: Like setting up `window.DISABLE_INDEXED_DB` at [aps-powerbi-tools/blob/develop/visuals/aps-viewer-visual/src/viewer.utils.ts#L18](https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-powerbi-tools/blob/develop/visuals/aps-viewer-visual/src/viewer.utils.ts#L18), specify `window.USE_OPFS = true` before including the viewer libraries.

Comment: And what does this cache do?

Comment: Found the answer: https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/viewer-performance-update-part-2-3-opfs-caching